# Jmeter Cookie on Jquery Library

Tags: jquery, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am running some charge test on an ASP.net application

I ma facing this issue with some Jquery Library

[image]

> GET [https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery->confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-%3Econfirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css)
> GET data:
> [no cookies]

[image]

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to cdnjs.cloudflare.com:443 [cdnjs.cloudflare.com/104.16.19.94, cdnjs.cloudflare.com/104.16.18.94] failed: Connection refused: connect
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:404)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2155)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2123)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:91)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
> ... 20 more

This issue can be related to cookies (null for this library)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the relevant details as text, rather than an image, so that everyone can read them and search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're "facing an issue" with `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` which algorithms consider your behaviour as malicious hence they block your IP (hopefully only your single IP) due to some form of [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)

Your load test setup is not very correct in terms of handling so called "embedded resources": images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.

It seems that you configured JMeter to retrieve these resources and you're using a [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to get them only once, but there is one major thing you missed: you should limit JMeter to get these resources **only from domain(s) specific to the application you're testing**, everything external, i.e. the stuff from cloudflare) should or even *[*must be excluded](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)**.

The relevant setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) so you could configure it in one place only)

[image]